# Will cffi:with-foreign-object free array elements?

Tags: memory-leaks, common-lisp, cffi

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
(defun do-some-fun-stuff (string-list)
  (let ((n (length string-list)))
    (cffi:with-foreign-object (array :string n)
      (loop for i below n
            for s in string-list
            do (setf (cffi:mem-aref array :string i) s))
      (call-some-foreign-function n array))))
```

I understand that `array` itself is going to be freed upon leaving the `with-...` block, but how about the *elements* of the array? The `(setf (cffi:mem-aref array :string i) s)` expression will allocate a null-terminated char* array for each element, right? Should I free them myself or CFFI will do that for me? I couldn't find a definitive answer neither in the documentation nor in the CFFI code.

Comment: The strings might be used elsewhere too, so it doesn't seem to make much sense for them to be automatically freed.

Comment: Yes, but -- if I wanted to pass ownership of these strings outside of the `with-..` block, I would allocate them with `cffi:foreign-string-alloc`.

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/cffi/cffi/blob/40d21df44959dab83a8ef0055a630a28fad85a84/src/types.lisp#L461

"...for each of the array's elements ... but there's a FIXME: **it doesn't free them yet**

Which means I have to free them manually.